# Number Theory Maths

Tags: number-theory

How to find the least number whose last digit is 7 and which becomes 5 times larger   when the last digit is carried to the beginning of the number?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please say more precisely what is meant by "last digit is carried..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the number is $N= 10A + 7$.  If we assume $N$ has $n+1$ digits and $A$ has $n$ digits, the putting the $7$ to the front is $7*10^n + A$.

So we want to solve $7*10^n + A  = 5(10A + 7)$.

So to solve for $A$ we have $49A =7*10^n - 35$ or

$7A = 10^n - 5$

We need to find the smallest value of $n$ where $10^n -5$ is divisible by $7$ or in other words where $10^n\equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

Or $3^n\equiv 5\pod 7$.  I'm not sure there is any option but brute force but $10, 7$ are relatively prime so we know there will be on value between $1$ and $6$.

$3^2 =9\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  $3^3 \equiv 3*2\equiv -1\pmod 7$.  $3^4 \equiv -3\equiv 4\pmod 7$.  And finally $3^5 \equiv (-3)*3\equiv -9\equiv -2\equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

So

$7A = 10^5 - 5 = 99995$ and $A = 14285$ and $N=142857$.

If I did this right we'd have $5*142857 = 714285$

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

Solve for increasing $n = 1, 2, \dots$ until you find a solution with integer $x$:

$$5\cdot (10x + 7) = 7\cdot 10^n + x$$

Then check whether the solution actually works, since $n$ needs to be $1 + \lfloor\log_{10} x\rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help

Answer (score 1):

Answer: $142857$.

Let our number be $x \cdot 10+7$ and have $k+1$ digits. Then $5(10x+7)=7\cdot 10^k+x$. Then $7x+5=10^k$. Since $10^k \equiv 5 (\mod{7})$ then $k=6n+5$, where $n \ge 0$. For least number we have $n=0$. Then $x=14285$.

Comment: Many thanks, Sir

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Why does $10^k \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ mean that $k =7n +5$?

Comment: If $n =1$ then $k=12$ we do not have $10^{12}\equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

Comment: By Fermat’s little theorem, the remainders are repeated with a period 6. Mistake $k=6n+5$.